# Can a virtual pageview be created in Google Analytics for an Android app?

Tags: android, ios, google-analytics, tags

Was looking around on the net for instructions on setting up virtual screenviews for the mobile version of Google Analytics. Could not find anything on the official documentation. Has anyone tried this? An example is, if there is a button in the app, instead of making it an event I would like to tag it as a virtual pageview.

Kindly share any info or pointers as to how to do this.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can:

```
  EasyTracker.getTracker().sendView("virtual button click screen view");
```

`"virtual button click screen view"` is the name of your screenview how it appears in google analytics afterwards.

see also [google analytics reference here](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/android/v2/screens)